# How to instance draw with different transformations for multiple objects

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

Im having a little problem with `glDrawArraysInstanced()`.

Right now Im trying to draw a chess board with pieces.

I have all the models loaded in properly.

Ive tried drawing pawns only with instance drawing and it worked. I would send an array with transformation vec3s to shader through a uniform and move throught the array with `gl_InstanceID`

That would be done with this for loop (individual draw call for each model):

```
for (auto& i : this->models) {
    i->draw(this->shaders[0], count);
}
```

which eventually leads to:

```
glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size(), count);
```

where the **vertex shader** is:

```
#version 460

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertex_pos;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 vertex_texcoord;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 vertex_normal;

out vec3 vs_pos;
out vec2 vs_texcoord;
out vec3 vs_normal;
flat out int InstanceID;

uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

uniform vec3 offsets[16];

void main(void){
    vec3 offset = offsets[gl_InstanceID];  //saving transformation in the offset 

    InstanceID = gl_InstanceID; //unimportant

    vs_pos = vec4(modelMatrix * vec4(vertex_pos + offset, 1.f)).xyz; //using the offset

    vs_texcoord = vec2(vertex_texcoord.x,1.f-vertex_texcoord.y);

    vs_normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(modelMatrix))) * vertex_normal;

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * vec4(vertex_pos + offset,1.f); //using the offset
}
```

Now my problem is that I dont know how to draw multiple objects in this way and change their transformations since `gl_InstanceID` starts from 0 on each draw call and thus my array with transformations would be used again from the beggining (which would just draw next pieces on pawns positions).

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can add : uniform int start_position; And then vec3 offset = offsets[gl_InstanceID+start_position];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got two problems. Or rather, you have one problem, but the natural solution will create a second problem for you.

The natural solution to your problem is to use one of the [base-instance rendering functions](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Instancing), like `glDrawElementsInstancedBaseInstance`. These allow you to specify a starting instance for your instanced rendering calls.

This will precipitate a second problem: `gl_InstanceID` *does not* respect the base instance. It will always be on the range [0, instancecount). Only [instance arrays](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Instanced_Array) respect the base instance. So instead of using a uniform to provide your per-instance data, you *must* use instance array rendering. This means storing the per-instance data in a buffer object (which you should have done anyway) and accessing it via a VS input whose VAO specifies that the particular attribute is instanced.

This also has the advantage of not restricting your instance count to `uniform` limitations.

OpenGL 4.6/ARB_shader_draw_parameters allows access to the `gl_BaseInstance` vertex shader input, which provides the `baseinstance` value specified by the draw command. So if you don't want to/can't use instanced arrays (for example, the amount of per-instance data is too big for the attribute limitations), you will have to rely on that extension/4.6 functionality. Recent desktop GL drivers offer this functionality, so if your hardware is decently new, you should be able to use it.

Comment: Which percent instancing in case of chess game will improve the performance?

Comment: @Hihikomori: 0%. It's a *chess game*; it has at most 32-pieces plus the board. On pretty much any hardware that exists, the per-object rendering costs will be a rounding error. Instancing will likely be *slower* than just rendering it straight (not that it would be a measurable difference).